# When do Postgresql update its statistical informations for CBO?

Tags: postgresql

I know the statistical information is updated by `VACUUM ANALYZE` and `CREATE INDEX`, but I'm not sure about some other situations:

1. insert new data into a table
2. let the database do nothing (and wait for autovacuum?)
3. delete some rows in a table
4. truncate a partition of a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE INDEX` does **not** cause new statistics to be calculated.

The autovacuum daemon will run an `ANALYZE` process for all tables that have more than 10% of their data changed (this is the default configuration). Theres changes are `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. `TRUNCATE` will clear the statistics for a table.